# Where to download .net 1.0 DLL's

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, decompiling

I need to decompile an old class library using Telerik JustDecompile. My problem is that the library is referencing things like System.Web.dll Version 1.0.5000.0, which is the .NET 1.0 version if I'm not mistaken.

All the PC's I have access to are running windows 7, so I can't simply install the 1.0 framework. So, I need to get my hands on the libraries some other way.

If I decompile the library without resolving the references, weird things happen like all the webmethods in the library are decompiled with empty [SoapDocumentMethod(,)], [[SoapHeader(,)]], etc. annotations.

I also need to resolve mscorlib.dll, System.Data.dll and System.Web, but it doesn't seem to matter if I manually add the references to a newer version after decompiling. It's just System.Web.Services that seems to be a problem.

Comment: Surely Windows 7 comes with .net 1.0 pre-installed?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't find the library in question on my machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Download [Microsoft .NET Framework Redistributable 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=96) (dotnetredist.exe)
2. Extract all files from **dotnetredist.exe** via 7-zip (or any another tool) -> (dotnetfx.exe)
3. Extract all files from **dotnetfx.exe** via 7-zip (or any another tool) -> (netfx.cab)
4. Extract all files from **netfx.cab** via 7-zip (or any another tool) -> 
   (System.Web_dll_5_____X86.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8)
5. **Rename** System.Web_dll_5_____X86.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8 to System.Web.dll
6. Profit!!!